# Get current users lotus notes database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

there is a way to pick up (by code) who are currently using a particular DB. It could be Java, Lotusscript, Formula, anything, I just want to know who is currently using it. I would put it in a agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!
In Domino Administrator there is a way to see who is using all databases in that server.
[Here's a example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXdTg.png)

Actually you see  "sh users" shell command in a beautiful way.

So what I did was use the "session.Sendconsolecommand('server', 'sh users')". It returns me the data on the above image in a String.

There was a pattern so I search in It if the user is currently using the DB.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no, there is no way. You could build a way in your own application by adding code that tracks each user whenever they open it, and timing them out to decide when they have stopped using it, but there's nothing built-in to do that.